# Object in Application can be null?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

In many class(Activity, Fragment, Adapter, ...), I need to access to objects.

So I put into Application class. (app, user)

**MainAppliction.java**

```
private static MainApplication singleton;

public static MainApplication getApplication() {
    return singleton;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    singleton = this;
}

private UserVo user; // I did not put null value
public UserVo getUser()(...)
public void setUser(UserVo user){...} // Called in LoginActivity
```

**ActivityA.java, ActivityB.java, ActivityC.java**

```
UserVo user;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    app = ((MainApplication) getApplicationContext());
    // or app = MainApplication.getApplication();
    user = app.getUser(); // Always Not Null
    //...
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    user.getData(); // Sometimes NullPointerExeception By GC (Maybe?)
}
```

How to Prevent Null Pointer Exception?

I think several idea. But I am not sure that they can be solution...

**1. Change UserVo user in MainApplication to Static memeber**

Like this(MainApplication.java)

```
private static UserVo user;
public static UserVo getUser()(...)
```

**2. Call getUser() not use UserVo Memeber**

Like this (Activity.java)

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    MainApplication.getApplication().getUser().getData();
}
```

**3. Make Inteface** (It is complex... I do not want to this)

Like this 
(MainApplication.java)

```
interface OnUser {
    void onUser(UserVo user);
}
public void getUser(OnUser onUser) {
    if (user == null)
        // Start Login Activity, and receive UserVo from Server.
    else
        onUser.onUser(user);
}
```

(Activity.java)

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    MainApplication.getApplication().getUser(new OnUser() {
        void onUser(UserVo user) {
            //Do Work.
        }
    });
}
```

Please give me some tips.

Answer (score 0):

> How to Prevent Null Pointer Exception?

Easy.

Initialize all your objects properly in the constructor so they're 100% ready to be used.  Don't allow any null references.

```
private static UserVo user;
```

As written, `user` is `null`.  Why?  Why static?  Why not a private data member that's initialized to point to a new `UserVo` reference on creation?

Otherwise you have to check for null everywhere before you use a reference.  It's a bad style that only gets worse as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check for nulls before you access the object after processing.
In fact it is always a good idea to check for nulls and handle a null (through java exception handling). Also, you could go for default initialization of your variable/references in such a way that the method call on the object does not create a side effect.
e.g. in case of an arrayList; declaring a variable like List `abc = new ArrayList();` would create an empty arraylist for you. Say after some processing logic, if the variable does not accumulate any data, it will remain empty; but would never throw a nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

> How to Prevent Null Pointer Exception?

The safest way to avoid a `NullPointerException` is to check object references to ensure that they are not null before accessing them.
While this approach will ensure you do not encounter unexpected NullPointerExceptions, it will also bloat your code, make it harder to develop, effect it's readability and it may hide unwanted situations in your code that will need to be handled eventually.

A better approach would be avoiding those null values in the first place. There are many ways of doing it. To name a few:

- Check Method Arguments for Null
- Consider Primitives Rather than Objects
- Carefully Consider Chained Method Calls
- Prefer [empty items](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=59) to null ones
- Avoid Returning Nulls
- Discourage Passing of Null Parameters

This [blog post](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.co.il/2009/04/effective-java-nullpointerexception.html) by [Dustin Marx](https://twitter.com/DustinMarx) nicely covers this topic.
I also recommend reading [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) (2nd Edition).

> Sometimes NullPointerExeception By GC (Maybe?)

The GC process will not collect an object if it has a strong reference from another live object, so this scenario is not possible. More likely is that the `user` object was not initialized before the `onResume` method was called.